# How to use useCallback on a custom hook?

Tags: reactjs, redux, jestjs, react-hooks, enzyme

I need this: `const setError = useError();` as a dependency in `useEffect`, but since this function is used in other places as well (within the same component), whenever an error is thrown, my `useEffect api` re-fetches data.

Should I just disable the `react-hooks/exhaustive-deps` rule or is there some way out of this? If I try to wrap it in `useCallback` I get an error that hooks can only be used within the component itself.

**edit**

```
export const useError = (): ((error: any, title?: string) => void) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
  const setError = (error: any, title = 'Error'): void => {
    Sentry.captureException(error);
    const bodyText = error.message || error;
    const errorTitle = error.name || title;
    dispatch(
      setNotification({
        type: notificationTypes.prompt,
        title: errorTitle,
        bodyText,
        className: 'error',
        show: true,
      })
    );
  };

  return setError;
};
```

Comment: can you show the implementation of useError

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri edited my question

Answer (score 6):

You can wrap the `setError` function with `useCallback with an empty dependency` in your custom hook before returning so that it is created only once

```
export const useError = (): ((error: any, title?: string) => void) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
  const setError = useCallback((error: any, title = 'Error'): void => {
    Sentry.captureException(error);
    const bodyText = error.message || error;
    const errorTitle = error.name || title;
    dispatch(
      setNotification({
        type: notificationTypes.prompt,
        title: errorTitle,
        bodyText,
        className: 'error',
        show: true,
      })
    );
  }, []);

  return setError;
};
```

With the above you might get a ESLint warning to add dispatch and Sentry as dependency to `useCallback` dependency array, you can add them to the dependency array since neither of `disptach` or `Sentry` would change